# Django upgrading unsalted MD5 password not matching

Tags: django, passwords

I am migrating an old system that uses unsalted MD5 passwords (the horror!).

I know Django [handles automatically password upgrading](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/passwords/#password-upgrading), as users log in, by adding additional hashers to the `PASSWORD_HASHERS` list in `settings.py`.

But, I would like to upgrade the passwords without requiring users to log in, [also explained in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/passwords/#password-upgrading-without-requiring-a-login).

So, I've followed the example in the docs and implemented a custom hasher, `legacy/hasher.py`:

```py
import secrets
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import PBKDF2PasswordHasher, UnsaltedMD5PasswordHasher

class PBKDF2WrappedMD5PasswordHasher(PBKDF2PasswordHasher):
    algorithm = "pbkdf2_wrapped_md5"

    def encode_md5_hash(self, md5_hash):
        salt = secrets.token_hex(16)
        return super().encode(md5_hash, salt)

    def encode(self, password, salt, iterations=None):
        md5_hash = UnsaltedMD5PasswordHasher().encode(password, salt="")
        return self.encode_md5_hash(md5_hash)
```

and add it to `settings.py`:

```py
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    "django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher",
    "legacy.hashers.PBKDF2WrappedMD5PasswordHasher",
]
```

However, testing this in the Django shell `check_password` is returning False for the upgraded password.

```py
>>> from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password, UnsaltedMD5PasswordHasher
>>> from legacy.hashers import PBKDF2WrappedMD5PasswordHasher
>>> hasher = PBKDF2WrappedMD5PasswordHasher()
>>> test_pwd = '123456'
>>> test_pwd_unsalted_md5 = UnsaltedMD5PasswordHasher().encode(test_pwd, salt='')
>>> print(test_pwd_unsalted_md5)
'827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b' # this is an example of a password I want to upgrade
>>> upgraded_test_pwd = hasher.encode_md5_hash(test_pwd)
>>> print(upgraded_test_pwd)
pbkdf2_wrapped_md5$150000$f3aae83b02e8727a2477644eb0aa6560$brqCWW5QuGUoSQ28YNPGUwTLEwZOuMNheN2RxVZGtHQ=
>>> check_password(test_pwd, upgraded_test_pwd)
False
```

I've looked into [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826908/python-django-unsalted-md5-password-hash-format) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56144262/django-convert-unsalted-md5-without-salt-hash-to-pbkdf2) SO questions, but didn't found a proper solution there as well.

Comment: You here generate `salt` yourself, that you do not "store" in the target password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: by not taking the provided `salt` into account, when verifying Django can not (likely) come up with the same encoded password.

The reason this happens is because you generate "salt" out of thin air, and ignore the `salt` that is passed. Indeed, if we take a look at your implementation, we see:

```
class PBKDF2WrappedMD5PasswordHasher(PBKDF2PasswordHasher):
    algorithm = "pbkdf2_wrapped_md5"

    def encode_md5_hash(self, md5_hash):
        salt = secrets.token_hex(16)  # generating random salt
        return super().encode(md5_hash, salt)

    def encode(self, password, salt, iterations=None):
        md5_hash = UnsaltedMD5PasswordHasher().encode(password, salt='')
        return self.encode_md5_hash(md5_hash)
```

The `salt` that is passed to the `encode(..)` method is thus ignored.

This means that if you later want to *verify* the password, Django will call `encode(..)` with the `salt` that it stored (in your case, that is the second part of the encoded password, so `f3aae83b02e8727a2477644eb0aa6560`), but you decide to throw that away, and generate the password with different salt, and therefore the encoded password, does no longer match with the password you did store in the database.

I advice to use the salt, for example with:

```
class PBKDF2WrappedMD5PasswordHasher(PBKDF2PasswordHasher):
    algorithm = "pbkdf2_wrapped_md5"

    def encode_md5_hash(self, md5_hash, salt):
        return super().encode(md5_hash, salt)

    def encode(self, password, salt, iterations=None):
        md5_hash = UnsaltedMD5PasswordHasher().encode(password, salt='')
        return self.encode_md5_hash(md5_hash, salt)
```

Comment: Oh, I was totally under the impression that my "salt handling" was not quite right. Thanks for the detailed answer. I got it working now.